# jQuery - Regex on value of each JSON key-value pair array

Tags: arrays, regex, json, jquery-ui-autocomplete, key-value

Suppose you have an array of JSON key-value pairs, such as the following:

```
var LNsIDs = [
    {2053 : 'Jones'},
    {9862 : 'Roberts'},
    {1567 : 'Collins'},
    {etc}
];
```

Is there a way to reference only the values of these pairs without dissociating them from their keys? (In other words, without looping through the array and feeding the values into a new array.)

I am performing a regular expression for an autocomplete function that works with a regular array. This part of the code would look like this:

```
$("#lastname").autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
        var esc = $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term);
        var regex = new RegExp("^" + esc, "i");
        var result = $.grep(LNsIDs, function(item){
            return regex.test(item.label);
        });
        response(result);
    },
    select: ...
```

This works with a regular array - for example, if the array was the following:

```
var LNsIDs = ['Jones', 'Roberts', 'Collins', etc];
```

BOTTOM LINE: How can I perform this regular expression on the values of these pairs in such a way that I can then retrieve the key of the selected pair?

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit difficult to determine exactly what you want, but maybe this will put you on the right track. It appears that the primary difficulty is that the objects in your `LNsIDs` array do not have consistent property names, so you cannot easily reference them. Here is a potential solution:

```js
var LNsIDs = [
    {2053: 'Jones'},
    {9862: 'Roberts'},
    {1567: 'Collins'},
];

var regex = /^R/i;
var result = $.grep(LNsIDs, function(item) {
    // Pull out the name of the first property on our object
    var key = Object.keys(item)[0];

    // Use the key to lookup and test the value of that property
    if (regex.test(item[key])) {
        // We match, so add two new properties to the object
        // before returning true:
        //
        // 1. The property name (i.e. 2053)
        // 2. The value of that property (i.e. Jones)
        item.key = key;
        item.label = item[key];
        return true;
    }

    // We don't match so we don't bother setting additional
    // properties
    return false;
});

// Once we have our result, it will just be an array of matches
// and each of the objects in it will have a 'key' and a 'label'
// property we can look at:
for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
    alert('Found match with key ' + result[i].key + ' and label ' + result[i].label);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was eventually able to achieve this by doing it the "right" way, which is to say, by putting an two separate AJAX calls in the *source* and *select* parameters of the autocomplete function, and outputting a traditional JSON array from my data source. Obviously, this would have been the correct way to perform this action all along. Thank you!